# MYSQL Database column id keeps track of insert - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I created a column in my database to keep track of the data that got insert.
When the application inserts for example 6 rows. All the 6 rows should have a ID of 1. When the application inserts data again the next X rows should have a increment ID (2).

DB example: column A should be the ID
[image]

i tried it with, but this gives all rows ID:1 and after another X uploads it al has ID. Than it just repeats itself

```
$id = DB::table('documents')->increment('uploadId');
```

Loop to save the data:

```
foreach ($excel as $key) {

            $obj = new Document();

              $obj->fill(array(
                'uploadId' => $id,
                'weld' => $key[1],
                'diameter' => $key[2],
                'thicknes' => $key[3],
                'surname' => $key[4],
                'steelgrade' => $key[6],
                'material' => $key[7],
                'weldingdate' => $key[10],
                'welderid' => $key[12],
                'requestid' => $requestId,
                'documentdate' => $date));
            }

          $obj->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use following statement as it works [differently](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#increment-and-decrement)

```
$id = DB::table('documents')->increment('uploadId');
```

So change that to following and give it a try

```
$nextID = DB::table('documents')->max('uploadId');

$nextID++;

foreach ($excel as $key) {
    $obj = new Document();
    $obj->fill(array(
    'uploadId' => $nextID,
    'weld' => $key[1],
    'diameter' => $key[2],
    'thicknes' => $key[3],
    'surname' => $key[4],
    'steelgrade' => $key[6],
    'material' => $key[7],
    'weldingdate' => $key[10],
    'welderid' => $key[12],
    'requestid' => $requestId,
    'documentdate' => $date));
}

$obj->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($excel as $key) {
$obj = new Document();
$obj->fill(array(
    'uploadId' => $id,
    'weld' => $key[1],
    'diameter' => $key[2],
    'thicknes' => $key[3],
    'surname' => $key[4],
    'steelgrade' => $key[6],
    'material' => $key[7],
    'weldingdate' => $key[10],
    'welderid' => $key[12],
    'requestid' => $requestId,
    'documentdate' => $date));
$i++;
}
$obj->save();
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your view

```html
<?php
 $ct = 1;
 ?>
```

```html
@if ($excel)

@foreach ($excel as $key) {

            $obj = new Document();

              $obj->fill(array(
                'uploadId' => $ct,
                'weld' => $key[1],
                'diameter' => $key[2],
                'thicknes' => $key[3],
                'surname' => $key[4],
                'steelgrade' => $key[6],
                'material' => $key[7],
                'weldingdate' => $key[10],
                'welderid' => $key[12],
                'requestid' => $requestId,
                'documentdate' => $date));
            }

          $obj->save();
           
          <?php $ct++; ?>

            @endforeach
            @endif
```

Make your $id=$ct